# jQuery with db Connection in Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery

**i am using jquery for slidshow. but i want the image url and description in db how to connect with jquery and db Like** 
    
    var imagesDataArray =[

```
{
src: 'images/bonsai.jpg',           
description: 'Test Description'        
 },        
{    
src: 'images/3.jpg'    
},    
{    src: 'images/forrest.jpg',     
description: 'Test description'    
}, 
{ 
src: 'images/leaves.jpg',
description: 'Test description'  
},  
{  
 src: 'images/village.jpg',  
description: 'Test description', 
 } 
];
```

jQuery(function(){

```
$('#unhookshow').shockwave(imagesDataArray, {
 'slider-type': 'UnhookedSlider',
 'random-time-to-unhook': 1500, // in ms 
 'free-fall-time': 150, // ms 
'autostart-slideshow': true,
'maximum-slideshow-cycles': 2, 
'slideshow-delay': 2000,
'duration': 100,.....
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: use ajax to connect to the db

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the task but you need to do ajax call for that .. which brings you list of images from the server.

Here is the list of post that helps you to achieve it

1. [Steps to Call WCF Service using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/steps-to-call-wcf-service-using-jquery.html)
2. [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html)
3. [Jquery Ajax Calling functions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html)

Comment: **How dynamic data add using server code to following Section**  [{ 
src: 'images/leaves.jpg',
description: 'Test description'  
},  
{  
 src: 'images/village.jpg',  
description: 'Test description', 
 } 
];

Answer (score 0):

use [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) OR [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)... send data to server .. connect to db in server.. and get the images

> $.ajax=>Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.
>
> $.post()=>Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

Comment: I thought this question for C#, not PHP